# Can loading packages that are built-in in Amsart incur any troubles?

Tags: amsart

Since I am not aware of which packages are Amsart built-in packages, I wonder if unconsciously loading the already-built-in packages leads to negative consequences.

I confess I have not yet found time to read the Amsart instruction manual.

Comment: There would be problems if you attempt to load a package using an option different from those which have been declared when the class internally loads the package.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Just came across some problems I suspected which to be caused by "double-loading", so I asked here. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be problems if you attempt to load a package using an option different from those which have been declared when the class internally loaded the package.

Since `amsart` only loads `amsmath`, `amsthm`, and `amsfonts` (unless the `noamsfonts` class option is used) with no options, an attempt to load any of those packages with package options will trigger an error; fortunately, `amsthm` and `amsfont` don't admit package options but, for example, the following code

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

will produce an error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package amsmath.
```

One way to prevent this would be to pass the options as a class (global) option:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

or, better yet, since `amsmath` was internally loaded already simply:

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{amsart}

\begin{document}
test
\end{document}
```

Additionally, the [`Instructions to authors`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/doc/instr-l.pdf) document recommends not to load `psfrag` and `epsfig` with AMS classes (the latter is an obsolete package which shouldn't be used anymore in any case).

Comment: the linked "instructions to authors" has been superseded by the [AMS author handbook](http://www.ams.org/authors/author-handbook); the "journal articles" version is appropriate in this situation.  although directed to authors submitting to the ams, it contains information on options, compatible packages, and similar matters (especially chapter 2, sections 3 ff.).  for reasons too complicated to explain here, the handbook is not available from ctan..

Comment: @barbarabeeton Thanks. I'll have a look at the handbook and will make any changes to my answer, if necessary.